# Nodes won't save?

Tags: mesh, shader-nodes

I have a mesh of a person that I'm trying to put textures onto.  I have a diffuse, normal and micronormal texture to add.  Here's what nodes I've been using

MICRONORMAL - Texture coordinate>Vector Mapping>Image Texture>MixRGB (slot 1)>Normal map.

NORMAL - Image Texture>MixRGB (slot 2)>Normal map.

DIFFUSE - Image Texture>MixRGB (to alter skin tone)

Everything is then plugged into the appropriate slots on a Prinicpled BDSF node and finally to the Material Output node.  This worked fine last night

I then exported as an .fbx file. However, when I reload the file, there's no textures on anything.  Everything is just blank white and the only nodes remaining are the BDSF, Normal map and Output nodes.

I've tried adding a fake user to the textures and adding each node in manually, but they're still gone again when I reload the mesh.  Like I said above, I did the same last night for the body textures and it saved fine.

Can anyone tell me:

1. What I'm doing wrong and why the textures aren't saving?
2. How to copy and paste the nodes properly to save time, as that's what seemed to cause the problem to start.

Don't know if it's important, but extra info:

The mesh was created in Character Creator 3, so all the textures were saved to a folder when I exported the mesh from that as an .fbx file.

Whilst I was working on the nodes, I noticed some of the pasted groups were appearing as individual nodes, as I'd copied them, but some were showing as a single green node group.

When I copied the nodes, I just box selected and right clicked and copy.  I didn't click 'group nodes' first.

Comment: Hi :). You need to save Blender files as .blend to make sure everything works.

Comment: about 2) If you have similar materials you can create a group & add this group by *Add > Group* ...  or duplicate the whole material with the *New Material* button right next to the *Fake User* button. You can also add the most frequently used nodes to the *Quick Favorites* menu (key Q to open it. Right-click on the menu entry to add it)